# Регулярное выражение - php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть множество строковых значений. Среди них нужно выделить те, которые начинаются на club и далее содержат только цифры. То есть отобрать нужно `club9324`, но не `clubmoscow`. Подскажите, как должно выглядеть такое регулярное выражение?

Answer (score 2):

Регулярное выражение для строки вида club9324 выглядит так:

```
%^club\d+$%
```

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регулярные_выражения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)